# Child prop value not updated on Window , but i can see it get updated in console

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I dont know what i am doing wrong in this code, the prop value 'number' is not updating on front end , although in the console logs it value does get increament.

```
  import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';


    class Parent extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.number=0;
            this.changeValue=this.changeValue.bind(this);
        }

        changeValue(){
            console.log('-------------this.number',this.number);
            this.number=this.number+1;
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <Child callMe={this.changeValue} increaseNo={this.number}></Child>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


    class Child extends React.Component{

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.props.callMe}>CLick Me</button>
                    <h1>{this.props.increaseNo}</h1>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    render(<Parent/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store `this.number` inside the component `state`, the component will only be re-rendered if its `state` changes or it receives new `props`.

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           number: 0
        }
        this.changeValue=this.changeValue.bind(this);
    }

    changeValue(){
        this.setState({number: this.state.number + 1});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Child callMe={this.changeValue} increaseNo={this.state.number}></Child>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class Child extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.props.callMe}>CLick Me</button>
                <h1>{this.props.increaseNo}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/55178/)

Comment: Thanks. Yes this solution works , But why 'this.number' didnt worked . Is it because React renders dom only when state is update. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: When the **component** state is updated or it receives new props, `this.number` was not part of the state nor it was a prop so Parent didn't re-render. You can read about the component lifecycle here, http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/2750/react-component-lifecycle#t=201609051001078991495